A question about dual connection in bundle AdE
I am currently studying Jost's book Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis seventh edition, Chapter 4 Section 2 Metric Connections. The Yang-Mills Functional. he defines an operator $D^*$dual to connection D, and proves that $D^*=*D*$, * is the Hodge star operator. I don't understand the part of the picture below

he says A operates on the form part by contraction, what is that mean? And I don't know how he got the following relationship(4.2.5)

Can anyone explain the details of this proof, or does anyone know of a book that talks about this operator in more detail?

I'm not sure I understand your confusion yet so maybe you can clarify if this doesn't answer it.
Normally in $D = d+A$, the $A$ acts by wedging, what Jost calls multiplication with dx^i:
$$D\omega = d\omega + A\wedge \omega = d\omega + A_i dx^i \wedge \omega.$$
But in $D^*$, A "acts by contracting" since the adjoint of wedging is contraction, aka interior multiplication.
In 4.2.5, Jost takes the adjoint of d (integration by parts).
$$\begin{align*}
\int \langle \nu, d \mu\rangle + \int \langle \nu, A_i dx^i \wedge \mu\rangle 
&= \int \langle d^*\nu, \mu\rangle - \int \langle A_i\nu, dx^i \wedge \mu\rangle 
\end{align*}$$
The minus sign is because the connection form is skew-adjoint.
Notice the wedge isn't moved over yet. If we continue
$$= \int \langle d^*\nu, \mu\rangle - \int \langle i_{(dx^i)^\sharp} (A_i\nu), \mu\rangle$$
where $(dx^i)^\sharp$ is the metric dual vector of $dx^i$.

Why does the first equality in (4.2.6) follow?
